# Abaqus python scripting documentation, how to work with it?

Tags: python, abaqus

I'm new to python scripting in Abaqus. I'm trying to make sense of the documentation but I don't get it. So far I found the following documentation:

1. This abaqus scripting user guide: http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.13/books/cmd/default.htm?startat=pt02ch06s01.html
2. This abaqus scripting reference document: http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.13/books/ker/default.htm

Now let's say that I want to know more about the OdbMeshElementArray class. How do I do this?

If I use the search function on the site than it just gives 0 hits.
If I download the pdf of the reference guide and I use ctrl+F then I do get hits, but there's no direct way to go to the page explaining specifically more about this class. E.g. I get a lot of hits of this search term in which I'm not interested. I just want to know the attributes and methods of this class.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Abaqus Scripting User Guide* is more of a beginner guide, which shows how things can be done. Similar to *Getting Started With Abaqus*, whereas *Abaqus Scripting Reference Guide* is the complete list of commands, classes and objects available. Similar to the *Abaqus Analysis User Guide*
2. The search function works for me as well, try using [Simulia Doc](http://help.3ds.com/2017/English/DSSIMULIA_Established/SIMACAEGSARefMap/simagsa-m-IntGetstartaba-sb.htm) hosted by DSS itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! The search function works here for me. It already finds occurrences for the MeshElementArray object. However it still doesn't explain what it is. (like is it a one dimensional, or a 2 dimensional array?). However I don't think it's in the reference guide, so I'll accept this as an answer. Thank you!

Comment: @ThaNoob It's just a list of OdbMeshElement objects. I noticed this documentation omission a while ago, too, but figured that's really all the OdbMeshElementArray is. Any link to it in the docs goes straight to the OdbMeshElement object description.

Comment: @MattP the link died

Answer (score 0):

[I found the documentation for the OdbMeshElement object?](http://ivt-abaqusdoc.ivt.ntnu.no:2080/v6.11/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch33pyo18.html)

You can use the side bar (on the left) to get the documentation for the other objects then too

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still don't really get it. I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that an OdbMeshElementArray object is still something different than an OdbMeshElement object. You said you found the documentation, how? Can you use a search term somewhere because it doesn't work for me.